# Is there a Image Gallery which will load all my posted Images like twitter's image grid?

Tags: plugins, themes, images, widgets, html5

Many of my wordpress posts have images in them for my personal blog. I have been searching for a good way to display all of the images from all of the posts in a grid layout on a page. Similar to the twitter grid layout [seen here](https://twitter.com/#!/_MikaelaDavis/media/grid).

I have seen [Next Gen Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery/), and was wondering if there is a way not just images from the current post, but ALL of the images from all posts into a collecting on one page.

Thanks

Comment: Just asking, if you've uploaded a few hundred images to your blog (or at least if that's going to happen over time), wouldn't it cause the page that shows "all of the images from all posts into a collecting on one page," take ages to load? (Unless of course they are going to be paginated — which you haven't mentioned.)

Comment: I suppose I should have been more specific. I would like to mimic the interface that the twitter has, where there are about 40 or so thumbnails, and as you scroll down javascript will populate new ones at the bottom. (The scroll down population is something I can do on my own, however I would like to use a plugin which can atleast generate thumbnails and arrange them in a grid from all my images)

Answer (score 1):

[Media Library Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/media-library-gallery/) plugin may be what you're looking for. And [here's a demo](http://www.morbleu.com/galerie-des-glaces/).

Comment: And it wasn't updated, in what, 3 years?

Comment: ya.. but still work, have you tried?

Comment: No offense, but it's not a good idea to use plugins which haven't been updated in years — **1.** Security concerns **2.** The next WordPress update may break the plugin, and what would the user do then? I am not trying to be rude, just trying to get my point across.